# PHP/Laravel - Admin being able to view a users table and editing the information

Tags: php, laravel

I recently finished a Java OCA course and we did a bit of PHP and I got interested in it. So to teach myself I'm making a phone book. The problem I've come across is that i have a few regular users who each have separate data entered and they can only see what they entered. I do this by having a "creator_id" being a foreign key in the contacts table so whenever a new contact is added they have their "creator_id" added and i can filter it out so they only see their own data.

I also added an admin user and i would like for him to be able to select a user and then go into that users contacts and manage them, like update, delete, add new ones etc. I got so far as to viewing the different users and i have a button under the form "show contacts" that should redirect me to that users contact table based o the "creator_id".

This is the ContactsController it has a search field and pagination:

```
public function index(Contacts $contacts)
{  
    $filter = request('filter', NULL);
    $contacts = NULL;

    if ($filter == NULL)
        $contacts = Contacts::query()->where('creator_id', auth()->id())->sortable()->paginate(5);
    else
    $contacts = Contacts::query()->where('creator_id', auth()->id())->where('name', 'like', '%'.$filter.'%')
                                 ->orWhere('number', 'like', '%'.$filter.'%')
                                 ->sortable()->paginate(5);

    return view('contacts.index')->withContacts($contacts);          
}
```

This is how a new contact is stored with the creator_id:

```
public function store(Contacts $contact)
{
    $validated = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:contacts,name',
        'number' => 'required|min:5|unique:contacts,number'
    ]);

    Contacts::create($validated + ['creator_id' => auth()->id()]);

    return redirect(route('contacts.index'))->withSuccess('Contact Created Successfully');
}
```

I have a ContactsPolicy with:

```
public function view(User $user, Contacts $contacts)
{
    return $contacts->creator_id == $user->id;
}
```

That's the only thing in there.And there's an AdminController which i have a middleware for:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->user()->isAdmin()) 
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('home');
}
```

That i use for my routes so only the person log in under admin can use in the users table i have a user type there's default and admin.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

const ADMIN_TYPE = 'admin';
const DEFAULT_TYPE = 'default';

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->type === self::ADMIN_TYPE;
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = Hash::make($password);
}
}
```

The only part in stuck on is allowing the admin to view other users contacts and add new ones or editing them under their creator_id?

Answer (score 0):

You can show a list of all the creators in the Admin form to create a contact.

```
<select name="creator_id">
   @foreach($creators as $creator)
      <option value="{{ $creator->id }}">{{ $creator->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

So whenever you post the form in the controller you can find the `$creator` by it's id and use that one to store a new contact.